# ggplot legends when plot is built from two data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, legend

I have data coming from two different data frames. I am trying to create legend for each data frame. I know I can combine the data frame and do it, but because of my data source  it makes the most sense to plot from two different data frames.

Please find the simplified example below. I have gotten close but the 'Main Forecast' in the legend is only white color. I want to show where 'Main Forecast' is red on the outside and white on the inside.

```
x = seq(1,10, 1)
y = seq(10,100, 10)

df  = data.frame(x=x, y=y)
df2 = data.frame(x=5, y=50)

p = ggplot(data=df) + 
  geom_point(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y, color="Weekly Forecast"), fill="red", size=5, shape=16)  + 
  geom_line(data=df,aes(x=x, y=y), color="red", size=1)  + 
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=y, color="Main Forecast"), size=2, shape=16)  +
  scale_color_manual("Legend Title", breaks=c("Weekly Forecast", "Main Forecast"), values = c("white","red"))
p
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't put `data =df`in the `ggplot()` call, just leave them in the geoms

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use one of the symbols that takes a fill (pch = 21:25). You then need to use `override.aes` to get the legend right. I've moved shared data and `aes` into the `ggplot` command.

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color="Weekly Forecast"), shape=16, size = 5)  + 
  geom_line(color="red", size=1)  + 
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(color="Main Forecast"), shape=21, fill = "white", size = 5)  +
  scale_color_manual("Legend Title", limits=c("Weekly Forecast", "Main Forecast"), values = c("red","red")) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(pch = c(16, 21), fill = c("red", "white"))))
```

This can also be done without `override.aes`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color="Main Forecast"), size=1)  + 
  geom_point(aes(color="Weekly Forecast", fill="Weekly Forecast"), shape=21, size = 5)  +
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(color="Main Forecast", fill="Main Forecast"), shape=21, size = 5)  +
  scale_color_manual(name="", values = c("red","red")) +
  scale_fill_manual(name="", values=c("white","red"))
```