# two legends when plot is built from two data frames

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have two data frames likes this:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(100)
y1 = rnorm(100)

x2 = rnorm(100)
y2 = rnorm(100)

df1  = data.frame(x=x1, y=y1, col1 = rep(1:4, each = 25))
df2 = data.frame(x=x2, y=y2, col2 = rep(5:8, each = 25))
```

I plot this data:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1,  colour = as.factor(col1)), data = df1, size = 1, shape = 19) +
  geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2,  colour = as.factor(col2)), data = df2, size = 2, shape = "\u2605")
```

The results is this:

[image]

How can I get two separate legends for each data frame?
The legends should also correctly reflect the shapes used and let me specify legend titles for each legend.

I know that [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38907371/ggplot-legends-when-plot-is-built-from-two-data-frames) exists but it's rather old and requires symbols that can take fills, I want to use custom unicode symbols.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via the `ggnewscale` package which allows to have additional scales and legends for the same aestethic. Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(100)
y1 = rnorm(100)

x2 = rnorm(100)
y2 = rnorm(100)

df1  = data.frame(x=x1, y=y1, col1 = rep(1:4, each = 25))
df2 = data.frame(x=x2, y=y2, col2 = rep(5:8, each = 25))

ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x1, y = y1,  colour = as.factor(col1)), data = df1, size = 1, shape = 19) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_color() +
  geom_point(aes(x = x2, y = y2,  colour = as.factor(col2)), data = df2, size = 2, shape = "\u2605")
```

[image]