# group legend values by a condition in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to group the full names of the characters by month_release which is binary (released, unreleased) such that the legend has two groups. If possible as well, it could reset the color schema for each group:

Code:

```
starting_vs_jp <- mutate(ur_characters, month_release = month(global_release)) %>%
  select(full.name, total.stats, month_release) %>%
  filter(month_release == 3| is.na(month_release)) %>%
  mutate(month_release = ifelse(is.na(month_release), 'Unreleased', "Released")) %>%
  arrange(month_release)

ggplot(starting_vs_jp) +
  geom_bar(aes(x=month_release, y=total.stats, fill=full.name), position='dodge', stat='identity')
```

Result at the moment:

[image]

Thank you for the help.

Comment: I think another way to ask this question is how do I make two legends.

Comment: I somewhat found a solution that works for this. I am going to use patchwork and then just add the plots. This sounds like the easiest and most efficient method. If there are better answers than this, then please post it.

Comment: `patchwork` is fine. Another option to achieve this in one plot would be the `ggnewscale` package. See my answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718912/two-legends-when-plot-is-built-from-two-data-frames/62719068#62719068 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493795/r-ggplot-heatmap-with-multiple-rows-having-separate-legends-on-the-same-graph/63494226#63494226